# Adding lines to a function

Tags: python, function

Suppose I had two functions within another function like so:

```
def FooBar(isTheWorldRound = True):

    def Foo():
        print("Hi, I'm foo.")

    def Bar():
        print("Hi, I'm bar.")

    theFunction = None
    if (isTheWorldRound):
        return Bar
    else:
        return [Bar, Foo]
```

So, I can do this:

```
myFunction = FooBar(False)
myFunction()
>>> Hi, I'm Bar
>>> Hi, I'm Foo
```

Concerning this example I have two questions:

1. What is the proper way to perform the commented line?
2. Is there a way I can do this without explicitly defining `Foo`?

Comment: Why do you think that won't work? You can certainly put functions in a list. And you aren't *"defining these inside another function"*, just referring to them. What are you actually trying to achieve (for example, what is the expected output)?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry I wasn't being clear. How about now?

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by *"without defining `Foo`"* - Python isn't (quite) magic, at some point you'll need to define the callables, either with `def` or a `lambda`.

Comment: Sorry, when I say "without defining" I mean "without explicitly defining". Would a lamba be acceptable here, then?

Comment: 1. How is a `lambda` **not** *"explicitly defining"*? 2. Acceptable to whom? In such a trivial case a `lambda` would be fine (or, as `print` is a function, use `functools.partial`) but I assume this is a toy example.

Comment: Yes it is, but I think we both understand exactly what I meant by "explicitly defining"

Comment: I can only assume you mean using `def` and are considering `lambda` to not be an explicit definition (though it is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting two functions into a list gives you just that; a list of functions. It **does not** make a new function that calls both of the previous functions. For that, you need to define a new wrapper function, e.g.:

```
def call_all(*funcs):
    """Create a new wrapper to call each function in turn."""
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        """Call the functions and return a list of their outputs."""
        return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func in funcs]
    return wrapper
```

*(if the `*` syntax is unfamiliar, see [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761))*, which you can now use like:

```
theFunction = call_all(Bar, Foo)
```

---

Note also that:

```
theFunction = None
if (isTheWorldRound):
    return Bar
else:
    return [Bar, Foo]
```

is a bit awkward, I would write it as:

```
if isTheWorldRound:
    return Bar
return [Bar, Foo]
```

You should also rename the functions/variables per [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Is there some way of using partial and apply?

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. So, if I understand your code correctly, the `wrapper(*args, **kwargs)` function will call each function in succession with the appropriate arguments. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, in this case you would have to explicitly name your arguments, as positional arguments would be taken in the applied order for the first function and then the second, or am I off base?

Comment: @Woody1193 it calls each function with whatever positional/keyword arguments you pass in, then returns a list containing the return values from each function (in this case, just `[None, None]`, but it's useful to have access in the more general case). You don't *need* to use only keyword arguments, the same positional arguments will also be passed to each inner function.

Comment: @PeterWood possibly, but note that [`apply` has been deprecated since 2.3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply).

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly compose a new function in a way `FooBar` will return a single function that evaluates one or both of them.

Consider this:

```
def F():
    funcs = [Foo, Bar]
    ret = None
    for f in funcs:
        ret = f()
    return ret
```

You can make a *closure* in your `FooBar` to return a single composition:

```
def FooBar(isTheWorldRound = True):
    if (isTheWorldRound):
        funcs = [Bar]
    else:
        funcs = [Bar, Foo]

    def theFunction():
        ret = None
        for f in funcs:
            ret = f()
        return ret
    return theFunction
```

Luckily this is easy in Python where functions are first-class objects.

Edit: seems you want to execute the functions directly during the execution of `FooBar`. Then you can ditch the closure but still call all the functions in a loop.

Comment: Cool, but could I do this without declaring `Foo()`?

Comment: @Woody1193: declare how? The functions can be inside `FooBar` or they can be even anonymous lambdas if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the commented line with:

```
return lambda: [None, Foo(), Bar()][0]
```

It will work as expected:

```
>>> myFunction = FooBar(False)
>>> myFunction()
Hi, I'm foo.
Hi, I'm bar.
```

What it does is creating an anonymous function, calling both `Foo()` and `Bar()` when invoked, and returning `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that should work. Without the parentheses, it's a function pointer (or whatever Python's equivalent is).

To call it, you'd do something like:

```
theFunction[0]()
```

To get the 0th function in the list, then apply the parentheses (or any arguments if needed).

Comment: I didn't downvote. Your answer requires using the return type differently depending upon the boolean passed as a parameter. This isn't a consistent interface.

Comment: He's changed the question since I answered it. Before, the question seemed to just be "can a store a function in a list". And everyone got down voted; not just me.

Comment: You might consider that a warning not to answer unclear questions without waiting for clarification!